How to implement Dart/Flutter unit test for the following scenario where there is a callback response from a service?
suppose I have a widget A and in the initState() lifecycle method of that widget i am calling a function
class A extends StatefulWidget{
// the usual dart code 
}
class _AState extends State<A>{
Service B = Service();
int counterId = 0;
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     B.initialize();
     _findId();
   }
      @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();B
  }

  Future<void> _findId() async{
    getfindId(
      (value) {
        setState(() {counterId = value;});
      }
    );
  }

  void getFindId() async{
     String uri = "uri-string";
     String args = "arguments-required";

     try{
        await B.getIdValue(uri , args , (response){
        Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response);
        int findIdValue = jsonResponse['vault']['findId'];
        callback(findIdValue);
        });
     }

     catch(e){
       print('error reported : $e');
     }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body : Center(
        child : Text(" the find id is : $counterId");
      )
    );
  }



the objective is to get the counterId value using a service
and for this operation I have a test case to check if the service is called and counterId value is updated.
@GenerateMocks([B])
void main(){
 group (" checking the service to get counteriD value" , (WidgetTester tester) async{
   final b = MockB();
   final response = {"vault": {"findId": 42}}
   when(b.getIdValue(any, any, any)).thenReturn((_) async =>future.value(response);
   await tester.pumpWidget(A());
   await A._findId();
   expect(A.counter , 42);
 }
}

in the test case i wrote - the idea is to pump the A widget and call the _findId but it is getting invoked inside the initState method. so i am guessing it gets call when I pump my widget into testing , so i am providing an implementation of the B.getIdValue method but this function calls a callback at the end of its execution .
How to handle this callback in the when method of unit testing ? also why is A._findId(); remains undefined ?
error i got when i tried to define when method -
when(b.getIdValue(any, any, any)).thenReturn((_) async =>Future.value(response);
Error: The argument type 'Future<String> Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'.
